# Ajax save to database in yii2

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, yii2

I am trying to insert to database yii2 using ajax, but I have a problem and it does not give me any errors at all. It shows success message like it works but nothing inserts. It does not reflect in the database.

this is my controller:

```
public function actionThumbs()
{
    $thumbs= new Thumbs; 
    if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
        $data = Yii::$app->request->post();
        $thumbs->user=Yii::$app->user->identity->email;
        $thumbs->topic_id=Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id');
        $my_array = explode(":", $data['rate']);
        $thumbs->rate=$my_array[0];
        $thumbs->load($_POST);
        $thumbs->save();
        return ['blog', 'id' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id')];
    }
    return $this->redirect(['blog','id' => Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('id')]);
}
```

this is my ajax file:

```
$("#mys").click(function() {
    var rate = "up";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'index.php?r=site%2Fthumbs',
        data: {
            rate: rate,
            _csrf: '<?=Yii::$app->request->getCsrfToken()?>'
        },
        success: function(rate) {
            alert("test");
        },
        error: function (exception) {
            console.log(exception);
        }
    });
});
```

my view file:

```
<div class="six columns">
    <?= Html::Button('ups', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 
 'name' => 'mys' ,'id'=>'mys']) ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: please indent your code properly

Comment: Can you post your model rules? I will help to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
  $thumbs->save(false);
```

if the value are inserted .. then check for your validation  .. rule in model ..

the false condition mean no validation .. the value are saved in db without performing any validation  rule

Comment: Did what you asked found out that the ide value was empty. That was why it did not insert. Saw the error in inspect element.